# Integrating wordpress CMS/backend with custom data source like REST API

Tags: wordpress, rest, content-management-system

Is it possible to use Wordpress and it's CMS (admin) UI (User Interface) along with custom data source like for example REST API? What I want is to use ONLY wordpress admin interface.

I have working REST api used by frontend (single page app) and now I have to build CMS backend. I thought about using Wordpress but I was wondering if it is possible and if it is good idea? Maybe you know other Services/Frameworks/Solutions for build CMS system? What I want is to minimalize time spent on coding CMS interface and just focus on presenting (and editing) data from REST API.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish what you want by writing a plugin and using the plugin api here http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

For example this
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post allows you to run code whenever a post is set to published (there are others for edit, delete etc)

for example

```
function notify_new_post($post_id) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    // connect to REST API HERE
    postToRest($post);
}

add_action( 'publish_post', 'notify_new_post' );
```

I would be tempted to leave the wordpress database untouched, and just use the API to sync the data to your current database. That way you can use all of the features of WordPress like saving post versions without any extra work for you.